# How to call javascript function loaded from js file url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function-call

I am loading javascript files from a url and these js files have some functions written in them.
I am loading these files using this function

```
public loadScript(url) {
  const node = document.createElement("script");
  node.src = url;
  node.type = "text/javascript";
  node.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(node);}
```

I am doing this in angular. I am able to call these functions from the browser console but i am not able to call these functions from HTML or ts file

Can you guys provide me any direction about how we can call these functions?

Thanks

Comment: If you insert the script-element after the page is loaded, it will never be evaluated by the browser. Is there any reason you need to load the script dynamically?
Otherwise just insert the script-tag in the HTML.

Comment: In the browser console log I am able to call these functions. 
yeah I need to upload some js files on the server and on getting those js files from the server I need to call them based on the value selected by a user from the dropdown
for eg if they selected sum i have to invoke sum function

Comment: This is normally not considered a good idea. 
Those functions could be written in their own module, lazy-loaded at application start, and called when needed.
Otherwise Angular might have a way to load extra functionality in a safe way.